# Problems after upgrade from a .NET Compact Framework 2.0 Application to 3.5

Tags: .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I tried to lift up my CF2.0(VS2005) Application to  to CF 3.5(VS2008) with the following steps:

- changed the Device from Windows Mobile 6.0  to Windows Mobile 6.5.3 DTK
- changed framework from CF 2.0 to 3.5

Compilation was successful. When I try to run it I receive a InvalidProgramException on startup. The exception is thrown when I try to set a Datagrid as owner of a DataGridTextBoxColumn.
<-- strange

I used PEVerify from Windows 7.0a SDK and got several errors. With ILDASM I was able to find the corresponding classes

```
[MD]: Error: TypeRef has a duplicate, token=0x010000c4. [Token:0x01000011] -> System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid
[MD]: Error: TypeRef has a duplicate, token=0x010000c3. [Token:0x0100006B] -> System.Windows.Forms.DataGridTextBoxColumn
[MD]: Error: TypeRef has a duplicate, token=0x010000ca. [Token:0x0100006C] -> System.Windows.Forms.DataGridColumnStyle
[MD]: Error: TypeRef has a duplicate, token=0x0100006b. [Token:0x010000C3]
[MD]: Error: TypeRef has a duplicate, token=0x01000011. [Token:0x010000C4]
[MD]: Error: TypeRef has a duplicate, token=0x0100006c. [Token:0x010000CA]
```

How could this happen and how can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by the use of ilmerge. 
I used ilmerge to merge all my dlls into the exe to reduce the deployment problems.
As it seems does ilmerge not work proper with cf 3.5 assemblies.

Comment: Mentioning that really critical detail in the original question would have helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Go to your form.
- Take note of the name of this DataGrid control (i.e. `dataGrid1`), then delete the DataGrid.
- Go to the Toolbox.
- Drop another DataGrid onto the form.
- Give the DataGrid the same name your original DataGrid had.
- Wire up your DataGrid events again.